# Angular + Express what's the standard way to indicate an empty db result set?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

is returning a null data object to my Angular controller and interrogating it there the correct way to indicate 'no user found' as below?  It seems like Mongoose or my own API should at least return {} which I could then interrogate for something concrete like data.username.

Of course I can make that happen but what is standard?

```
(Express code)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('/api/memberconfirm/:code', function (req, res) {

    return db.userModel.findOne({'confirmcode': req.params.code}, function (err, data) {
         if (!err) {
              return res.send(data);
         }
         else {
              console.log("error");
              return something...
         }
    });
});


(Angular code)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
controllerModule.controller('MemberConfirm', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location',

      function MemberConfirm($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
            var url = '/api/memberconfirm/' + $routeParams.param1;

            $http.get(url)
                 .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        /*
                             null means no user found? 
                        */
                        if(data) {
                             $location.path("/login");
                        }
                        else {
                             $location.path("/memberconfirmfailed");
                        }
                 })
                 .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("not ok");
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                 });
      }
]);
```

Comment: `res.send(404)` maybe?

Comment: for login fails, I use 401 Unauthorized

Comment: This is not about login failure it's about whether a null object (data) should represent a 0 record result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST uses HTTP response codes, so `404` indicates not found. Also, note that Mongoose returns `null` if nothing is found. It only returns `err` for actual errors (like a DB error).

For the server-side code:

```
return db.userModel.findOne({...}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { /* handle the error */ }
    else {
        if (data) { return res.send(data); }
        else { return res.send(404); }
    }        
});
```

For the client-side code:

```
$http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      /* found: do stuff */
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      if (status === 404) { /* not found */ }
      else { /* some other error to deal with */ }
    })
;
```